# Suddenly can't open my localhost/phpmyadmin in xampp

Tags: php, xampp

Problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhy2h.png

NOT WORKING the problem still persists!

$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;

post_max_size = 750M

upload_max_filesize = 750M

max_execution_time = 5000

max_input_time = 5000

memory_limit = 1000M

max_allowed_packet = 200M

Comment: What does your mysql.log file report?

Comment: your clearly not using the values above or php would not time out after 30 seconds, not that changing that is really the answer.

Comment: I have assumed you you already restarted xampp and apache.

Comment: thanks already solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to change the value from 0 to 6000. e.g

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

To

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;
```

Then restart xampp server.